# Keyboard shortcuts in WPF MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, keyboard-shortcuts

I have WPF application that follow MVVM pattern. I need to implement keyboard shortcuts. These shortcut have to contol WebBrowser control behaviour. I defined first custom command and added to view's inputbindings. There will be much more commands and they would have to invoke scripts on browser:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
        ...

        CommandBinding cb = new CommandBinding(RemoteControlCommands.TestCommand, MyCommandExecuted,  MyCommandCanExecute);
        this.CommandBindings.Add(cb);

        KeyGesture kg = new KeyGesture(Key.Q, ModifierKeys.Control);
        InputBinding ib = new InputBinding(RemoteControlCommands.TestCommand, kg);
        this.InputBindings.Add(ib);
    }

    private void MyCommandExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser.InvokeScript("foo", "Hello World!");
    }

    private void MyCommandCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = true;
    }
```

**My question is how to fit this into MVVM patern?** MVVM is a new concept to me but I understand how to bind view's command to view model and there execute methods or change properties. 
However what I need in this case is to execute a method on a control in the view. What is the best place to shortcut handling in this scenario?

Answer (score 47):

```
<Window.InputBindings>
  <KeyBinding Command="{Binding MyCommand, Source=viewModel...}"
              CommandParameter="{Binding,ElementName=browserControl,Mode=Self}"
              Gesture="CTRL+R" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

You can bind command property to View Model's command.

Comment: and then? view model does not know about webbrowser control in view that I want to invoke method on

Comment: You can bind command parameter to some value like webbrowser itself and retrieve it in your delegate method.

Comment: Please notice that Akash Kava's answer will only work on .NET 4.0 on, since `KeyBinding.Command` and `KeyBinding.CommandParameter` are not dependency properties as of .NET 3.5.

Comment: Another caveat to note; if you include guards with the bound command, Caliburn will disable the entire view when the guards evaluate false. I worked around this problem by having 'overloads' of the action with different names for the keyboard shortcuts and for any related controls (e.g; menu items) which were invoking the same command